# Why can't I access a value from this array using a functionally calculated int as an index?

Tags: c++, arduino, adafruit

EDIT: I mistakenly assumed I should ask this as a general C++ question, and realized later that this issue came from my usage of C++ within the Arduino environment. In my example, I didn't include my usage of an Arduino modifer `PROGMEM` on the array which moved its storage from RAM to FLASH and is ultimately what caused the calculation issue. Accessing the PROGMEM array required me to use an accessor method `pgm_read_byte` instead of an index.

I have an array:

`const PROGMEM uint8_t daysInMonth[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};`

I have a functionally calculated uint8 from a time library:

`uint8_t month = tm.month();`

I have a size_t:

`size_t monthIndex = (size_t)month;`

I've tried using either `month` or `monthIndex` to access a value from this array, however the same result happens:

```
# For size_t monthIndex = 1 or uint8 month = 1; ...
uint8_t currentDaysInMonth = daysInMonth[monthIndex];

# >> Expected = 28;
# >> What I actually get = 61;
```

How do I get the expected array value?

Where is 61 coming from?

**EDITS**

This is the relevant portion of the DateTime class for `tm`

```
class DateTime {
public:
  DateTime (uint16_t year, uint8_t month, uint8_t day,
              uint8_t hour = 0, uint8_t min = 0, uint8_t sec = 0);

  uint8_t month() const       { return m; }
}
```

Datetime constructor

```
DateTime::DateTime (uint16_t year, uint8_t month, uint8_t day, uint8_t hour, uint8_t min, uint8_t sec) {
    if (year >= 2000)
        year -= 2000;
    yOff = year;
    m = month;
    d = day;
    hh = hour;
    mm = min;
    ss = sec;
}
```

Minimal example:

```
DateTime tm = DateTime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0);

const PROGMEM uint8_t daysInMonth[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

uint8_t month = tm.month();

uint8_t currentDaysInMonth = daysInMonth[month];

>> currentDaysInMonth Returns 61
>> expect 31 from this example, though would offset index - 1 once I figure out what the issue is.
```

Print logs:

```
std::cout << month << std::endl;
std::cout << tm.month() << std::endl;
std::cout << currentDaysInMonth << std::endl;

# >> 2
# >> 2
# >> 219 -- sometimes its 61, 45, 219, not sure the rhyme or reason to this value
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: There's also no need (from what I can see with the limited information we have) that you need the `monthIndex` temporary variable. You could just as well use `month` directly as the index.

Comment: `tm` is a DateTime class - I'll add it to the question

Comment: Show the definition of the `DateTime` constructor too. You've only shown the declaration.

Comment: Probably unrelated: `DateTime tm = DateTime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0);` would be better as `DateTime tm(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0);`.

Comment: adding the constructor too...

Comment: What is the value of `tm.m`? What is the value of `month`? Either use a debugger to step through the code while monitoring all relevant variables and their values, or print them out every time there is any chance of them changing.

Comment: `DateTime` has no members as per your code. Look, we want to help you, but if we can't _compile_ the code you are giving us (because it is missing crucial aspects) then it becomes almost impossible to tell what the real problem is. On the other hand, if you can give us code that we can copy-paste into e.g. `godbolt.org` and it reproduces the problem, you are virtually guaranteed to get an answer: https://godbolt.org/z/w7wBuX

Comment: I understand. I'm not 100% sure how to get all the code I need from the timelibrary's github page https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/blob/master/RTClib.cpp but I'll edit my question with my console logs if that helps anyone... if not sorry I can't add more info and thanks everyone for your help

Comment: Added print logs

Comment: Unsure if related, but would the memory environment impact this at all? This is running in an extemely low memory environment (32K flash memory 1028b sRam) arduino.

Comment: It's hard to find errors in those code fragments from a lib mixed with your code. You should make a small, complete, example that anyone who has the Arduino environment could compile as-is. You don't need to include the library code, just mention that `DateTime` is from the adafruit RTCLib. Also add the proper tags to your question to attract people that may have the knowledge needed. I added two tags to your question. I would have added `RTCLib` too, but that tag wasn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistakenly assumed I should ask this as a general C++ question, and realized later that this issue came from my usage of C++ within the Arduino environment. In my example, I didn't include my usage of an Arduino modifer PROGMEM on the array which moved its storage from RAM to FLASH and is ultimately what caused the calculation issue. Accessing the PROGMEM array required me to use an accessor method pgm_read_byte instead of an index.

Solution:

```
DateTime tm = DateTime(2020, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0);

const PROGMEM uint8_t daysInMonth[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

uint8_t month = tm.month();

# use the pgm_read_byte accessor
uint8_t currentDaysInMonth = pgm_read_byte(&daysInMonth[month - 1]);
```

Thanks everyone for your help! Sorry for the initial lack of information.

Some resources:

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/tr/language/variables/utilities/progmem/

https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PROGMEM.html